# Close message caused by user attempting to edit locked cell in protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

How do I automatically close an Excel message caused by a user attempting to edit locked cell in a protected sheet?

This isn't occurring during a macro. I want to create a macro that will run when a pop up message occurs in order to close that pop up.

I tried clicking the 'Record Macro' button then re-creating the conditions by attempting to edit a locked cell, which causes the message to occur, which I closed by clicking on the OK button of the message, then ending the recording. I'm forced to assign it to a Shortcut key, but this Shortcut key does not do anything, likely because my code is wrong or because I don't have the right approach.

I suspect the error message is not part of VBA and cannot be dealt with via VBA.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/how-can-i-disable-the-warning-pop-ups-on-protected-cells-to-make/m-p/1343494

Comment: [DisplayAlerts property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dzh-TW%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133119)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) What I know is that it is possible not to display error messages while the program is running, but if you want to use the VBA to end the messages built into the system, I'm afraid you can't do that unless you add a new form to achieve it.  https://www.google.com/search?q=Close%20a%20message%20box%20by%20vba

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the error from occurring upstream.
When you protect the sheet, uncheck the box

```
Select locked cells
```

in this way the user will not be able to attempt to modify those cells in any way because the selection will never be positioned on them.